# Filter() - referencing source array in criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-arrays

The filter() function looks through a source array, and filters it according to condition
`=FILTER(A:A,ISNUMBER(A:A))`.

My source array is a rather long formula, so I end up repeating the same formula twice in the `ISNUMBER()` condition:

`=FILTER(ARRAYFORMULA(1+(SORT(TRANSPOSE(FILTER($N9:9,ISNUMBER($N9:9),$N$3:$3="Skills [s]")),1,FALSE))*StackPenalty),  ISNUMBER(ARRAYFORMULA(1+(SORT(TRANSPOSE(FILTER($N9:9,ISNUMBER($N9:9),$N$3:$3="Skills [s]")),1,FALSE))*StackPenalty)))`

Is there any way I can write this shorter?
Any way to reference the source array by some name?
Index?
Any way to use ISNUMBER() condition without passing the whole source array?

To recap: I need a way to reference the first argument of `Filter()` function in the second argument to that function, without repeating the whole argument explicitly.

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aq6pdGj-zwyedEt0NFdhRDYzY25HVHl5S0o2UlEwMFE&usp=sharing).  Sheet "Fitting Tool", cell L18 (change N9:9 in formula to N18:8), but this will be repeated throughout the L:L column.

Comment: Can you share a doc with us?

Comment: Added link to OP

Comment: Sorry, i only saw the comments from some people looking into this right now. I've reverted the spreadsheet and saved it under a different link (read OP). Thank you

Comment: Is this the original sheet?

Comment: Sheet `Weapons` doesn't exist.....

Comment: I started preparing everything in Google Apps Script, to work as an arrayformula. Will this help you as well?

Comment: No, this is a copy of the original that i placed elsewhere randomly (yes... i know... ). Please ignore the Weapons sheet. It is not required for the formula in cell L18. As for Google Apps Script, i am really not familiar with that, but if you can use that to answer my OP, i will take it.

Comment: The first cal. in the mod formula (col j, `=IFERROR( PRODUCT( ARRAYFORMULA( 1+FILTER( FILTER(ModStats,ModAttrb="% "&$G4),ModHeader="Skills") ) ), 1)`), yields 0 every time. What's the point in performing this calc. if col G contains no %-sign is present...

Comment: Col J uses value of G, for example "CPU". It then applies modifications to this, based on table M3:S19. In that table, there are entries for "CPU" and "% CPU". Both need to be applied to value of G (and they are slightly different). The search for %-sign is in the M3:S19 table, not in G column

Comment: BTW, i have 21 hours to award the bounty on an answer (and there is no answer yet). If you will post your script solution as answer, i could award the bounty on it. Not sure what happens after 21 hours... i guess i will just lose the rep, so i'd rather give it to you for the effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been working on your file, even before the bounty period, and it as been a struggle. I wanted to give you the automation te `ARRAYFORMULA` can give in combination with a bit of Google Apps Script. In doing so, I wanted to understand the calculations a bit and thus I started with optimizing the first formula for column E:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A4:A<>"";ARRAYFORMULA(A4:A*D4:D);""))`

For column H, I created to following formula:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G4:G30;Suits!A:AC;{MATCH(H2, suits!A1:AC1 ,0)}*SIGN(ROW(G4:G30));0),""))`

For column I, I created the following script:

```
function skills(array1, array2, array3) {
  var array = new Array();

  for(i=0, len2=array2.length; i<len2; i++) {
    var prod = 1;
    for(j=0, len1=array1.length; j<len1; j++) {
      if("% " + array2[i][0] == array1[j][0]) {        
        prod *= array1[j][2] + 1;        
      }      
    }
    var value;
    if(array3[i][0] == "") {
      value = "";
    } else {
      value = prod * array3[i][0];
    }
    array.push([value]);
  } 
  return array;
}
```

For column J, I created te following script:

```
function mods(array1, ModAttrb, ModHeader, ModStats, array5, array6) {
  var array = new Array(), aSecond = new Array(), aThird = new Array();

  // second calculation  
  for(i=0, len1=array1.length; i<len1; i++) {    
    var secondSum=0;    
    for(j=0, len2=ModAttrb.length; j<len2; j++) {      
      if(array1[i][0] == ModAttrb[j][0]) {        
        for(l=1, len4=ModStats[0].length; l<len4; l++) {
          if(ModStats[j][l] == 0 || ModStats[j][l] == "") {
            secondSum += 0;
          } else {
           secondSum += ModStats[j][l];
          }
        }
      }
    } 
    aSecond.push(secondSum);
  } 

  // third calculation
  for(i=0, len1=array1.length; i<len1; i++) {
    var thirdSum=0;
    for(m=0, len5=array5.length; m<len5; m++) {
      if(array1[i][0] == array5[m][0]) {        
        thirdSum += parseInt(array5[m][3]);        
      }      
    }
    if(thirdSum == 0) {
      thirdSum = 0;
    } 
    aThird.push(thirdSum);
  }  

  for (var i=0; i < aSecond.length; i++) {
    var result = 0;
    result += (array6[i] * 1 + parseInt(aSecond[i]) + parseInt(aThird[i]));
    array.push([result])
  }  
  return array;
}
```

Here, for the sake of time, I set the first calculation to be 1.

After that, time was running short. The Mult column is/was difficult to comprehense. We can work on it afterwards if you want?

See te example file I copied in te beginning: [Fitting Tool](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdHhKRWU5eGtqRWc2LTN0REg3QU5GbEE&usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks, you've done a lot of work, i will have to look into everything that you've done to understand it

Answer (score -3):

Plz all these two functions in your script editor and run and than
=SHEETNAME() in any cell will return you the result

```
function SHEETNAME() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveRange().getSheet();
  return s.getName();
}

function GETSHEETKEY() {
  //Browser.msgBox('Spreadsheet key: ' + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId());
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()
  return s;
}
```

Comment: Does this really answer the question?